# How to export form data

Tags: javascript, html, export

I am newbie to JS and learning how to export the data when the submit button of the particular form is clicked and My code is like below:

```
var stockData = [
        {
            Email:document.getElementById("email").value,
            Password: document.getElementById("pwd").value,
            Name: document.getElementById("name").value,
        }

    ];
    function downloadCSV(args) {
        var data, filename, link;

        var csv = convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV({
            data: stockData
        });
        if (csv == null) return;

        filename = args.filename || 'export.csv';

        if (!csv.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
            csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + csv;
        }
        data = encodeURI(csv);

        link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute('href', data);
        link.setAttribute('download', filename);
        link.click();
    }
```

[Code pen](https://codepen.io/RKR3/pen/MGVWRd)

But when I export the data I always get empty even if I enter value in the fields.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You’d better show the form html to help us with your issue

Comment: He did. There is a link to CodePen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you take value of fields when js is loaded and not when user clicks the button.

Notice `stockData` variable declaration. I moved it to function `downloadCSV()`.

**Here is working solution**

```js
function convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV(args) {
  var result, ctr, keys, columnDelimiter, lineDelimiter, data;

  data = args.data || null;
  if (data == null || !data.length) {
    return null;
  }

  columnDelimiter = args.columnDelimiter || ',';
  lineDelimiter = args.lineDelimiter || '\n';

  keys = Object.keys(data[0]);

  result = '';
  result += keys.join(columnDelimiter);
  result += lineDelimiter;

  data.forEach(function(item) {
    ctr = 0;
    keys.forEach(function(key) {
      if (ctr > 0) result += columnDelimiter;

      result += item[key];
      ctr++;
    });
    result += lineDelimiter;
  });

  return result;
}

function downloadCSV(args) {
  var data, filename, link;
  var stockData = [{
    Email: document.getElementById("email").value,
    Password: document.getElementById("pwd").value,
    Name: document.getElementById("name").value,
  }];
  var csv = convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV({
    data: stockData
  });
  if (csv == null) return;

  filename = args.filename || 'export.csv';

  if (!csv.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
    csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + csv;
  }
  data = encodeURI(csv);

  link = document.createElement('a');
  link.setAttribute('href', data);
  link.setAttribute('download', filename);
  link.click();
}
```

```html
<link rel="icon" href="https://image.ibb.co/fb4f8y/Test_Form_Icon.png" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>TestFormData</h2>
  <form class="form-horizontal" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Name:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" name="name">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick='downloadCSV({filename: "data.csv"});'>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```